# Creating CGA rules in ESRI CityEngine?

Tags: references, cityengine

I'm new in using ESRI CityEngine 2011. I read it's tutorials. It was very interesting and helpful for but there is no references or tutorials for how to create CGA rules. How can I find any tutorials  about this subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a link to a presentation given at the recent ESRI Developer Summit: Developing with ESRI CityEngine.

http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit12/papers/developing_with_esri_cityengine.pdf

There are also some video tutorials here:

http://video.arcgis.com/watch/1772/tutorial-6-basic-shape-grammar

Additional resources:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/52242-Learning-CityEngine-Tutorials-and-other-Training

Answer (score 0):

The CityEngine help also contains an introduction to the principles of CGA.

You can find it in Help Menu -> Help Contents -> Manual -> Rule-based Modeling (also available on the [web](http://cehelp.esri.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.procedural.cityengine.help/html/manual/cga/basics/toc.html)).